# How to create a button or text using jQuery to display an image

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to create a button or text, that I can click that will toggle an image to display a map. Such as:

JavaScript:

```
 $('.buttontest').click(function () {
     $(this).parent().find('img.locationMap').toggle('slow');
 }); // End of $('.buttontest').click(function()
```

HTML code

```
 <div id="location">
     <button class="buttonTest" value="Show/Hide 1">
     <img src="graphics/locationMap.png" id="location" />
 </div>
```

I can't seem to get this to work. It just displays the image as the button, but when clicked it doesn't return an error or anything.

Comment: @JánosWeisz Formatting and indenting code is great to make it more readable but please do not change the structure, i.e. fixing the `img` tag. This can break the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your button has class `buttonTest` but the javascript references as `.buttonTest` with a capital T. Javascript is case-sensitive, so it is not hooking up your click event handler.

Also your image does not have class `locationMap` so that will not get matched either.

Lastly, you have 2 elements with `id="location"`, which is invalid. You need to change or remove the id of one of them. And some html is wrong.

Try this instead:

```
 $('.buttonTest').click(function() 
 {
     $(this).parent().find('img').toggle('slow');
 });


 <div id="location">
     <button class="buttonTest">Show/Hide 1</button>
     <img src="graphics/locationMap.png" />
 </div>
```

Comment: This works great! But is there a way to have it so when the page loads it doesn't display the image right away? So it just shows the button, then when you click you can display the image.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTML is not valid. You did not close button tag. This should help

```js
$('.buttontest').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().find('img').toggle('slow');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="location">
    <button class="buttonTest">Show/Hide 1</button>
    <img src="graphics/locationMap.png" id="location"/>
</div>
```